# I have 2 JAVA projects in my eclipse one is maven-testNG and 2nd one is maven-cucumber. In cucumber project Illegal character in path

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, cucumber

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 0: {StepDefinitions}

My project path in runner class--
"C:\Users\punia\OneDrive\Desktop\Selenium Project All\Eclipseworkspace\CucumberFoodwatch\src\test\resources\features"

I have also tried path using %20--
"C:\Users\punia\OneDrive\Desktop\Selenium%20Project%20All\Eclipseworkspace\CucumberFoodwatch\src\test\resources\features"

Below is my runner class file ----

```java
package runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="C:\\Users\\punia\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Selenium Project All\\Eclipseworkspace\\CucumberFoodwatch\\src\\test\\resources\\features",
glue= "{StepDefinitions}",
plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"})

public class TestRunner {

}
```

---

below is my pom.xml file---

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.Cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>CucumberFoodwatch</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-rc-1</version>
        </dependency>





    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execution</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <projectName>CucumberFoodwatch</projectName>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                            <cucumberOutput>${project.build.directory}/cucumber.json</cucumberOutput>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of providing absolute path you can provide relative path as below.

```
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/resources/features",glue= "{StepDefinitions}",plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"})
```